# Programmatically pinch out

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, viewport

I am creating a jQuery Mobile site wrapped in PhoneGap. I want to enable pinching in the gallery section, but disable it elsewhere.

I can change the meta tag that controls maximum-scale when entering the gallery, but if the user leaves the gallery section pinched in, he is (counter intuitively) unable to pinch out, when I set the maximum-scale back to 1.0, which leaves him stuck in a magnified UI.

Is there is a way to set the maximum-scale back to 1.0 and also forcefully scaling the user back to the initial scale at the same time?